# Is there a way to re-provide all the names that have been required?

Tags: scheme, racket, require

This is what I have:

```lisp
;; module A
(require X Y)  ;; provides foo and bar
(define stuff (list foo bar))
```

...and this is what I want to work:

```lisp
;; module B
(require A)
(foo 2 3) ;; error because foo is not defined
```

This is a workaround:

```lisp
;; module A
(require X Y)
(provide foo bar) ;; annoying to have to type when the list is really long
(define stuff (list foo bar))
```

Is there a way to avoid repeating `foo` and `bar` twice?

So far, I tried `(map provide list)` (an error), and `(provide (all-defined-out))`, which provides `stuff` but not `foo` or `bar`.

Comment: Have you looked at [`all-from-out`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._all-from-out%29%29)? As in `(provide (all-from-out X Y))`

Comment: I'm using `(require "path/too/filename.rkt")` which contains `foo` and so on. I guess it makes some difference when it's a module name vs. a path.

Comment: So I guess if X is that relative-path string, then the (provide (all-from-out X)) would be `(provide (all-from-out "path/too/filename.rkt"))`